# Add to function pointer, to get pointer to another function?

Tags: c, ruby, function-pointers, addition

I have been fiddling with function pointers, and I have two specific fuctions I've printed to the console; the results say they are 8 bytes appart, like so:

```
Function Pointer Addresses:
rb_gc_start addr: 0x6ea81360
rb_gc_mark  addr: 0x6ea81368
```

Could I simply get a function pointer to the first, add 8 to that pointer, and have a pointer to the second function?

Backstory: There exists two functions in Ruby's source, `rb_gc_start` and `rb_gc_mark`; I'm building a library for a...difficult program. This program embeds Ruby, but not the Ruby C API (it disables loading Ruby extensions, or *.so files). I've pretty much recreated the environment, and I can get the address of `rb_gc_start` directly, but `rb_gc_mark` is not so easily exposed, and I need a pointer to it for everything to work right.

For instance:

```
unsigned long (*rb_gc_start)(void);
void (*rb_gc_mark)(unsigned long);

void my_method(void) {
    rb_gc_start = get_method(rb_mGC, "start"); // 0x6ea81360;
    rb_gc_mark = rb_gc_start + 8; // Does this work?
}
```

I most likely look the fool here, but any help on obtaining the second function would be most helpful.

Comment: Where does `func1_ptr` come from?

Comment: Sorry, I renamed the functions at last minute to provide more context; it should be `rb_gc_start`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may not do this if the function pointers are not in the same array of function pointers. The additive operator for pointers and integral values is valid only for pointers in an array. A single object is considered as an array with one element.

Also take into account that according to the C Standard (6.2.5 Types)

> 28 A pointer to void shall have the same representation and alignment
>   requirements as a pointer to a character type.48) Similarly, pointers
>   to qualified or unqualified versions of compatible types shall have
>   the same representation and alignment requirements. All pointers to
>   structure types shall have the same representation and alignment
>   requirements as each other. All pointers to union types shall have the
>   same representation and alignment requirements as each other.
>   **Pointers to other types need not have the same representation or alignment requirements.**

And (6.3.2.3 Pointers)

> 8 A pointer to a function of one type may be converted to a pointer to
>   a function of another type and back again; the result shall compare
>   equal to the original pointer. **If a converted pointer is used to
>   call a function whose type is not compatible with the referenced type,
>   the behavior is undefined.**

Comment: Is there anything you can suggest for me to do? The Ruby environment is a dll embedded into their program, so I can't access it; is there any way to get a handle to that function?

Comment: @FenixFyreX The functions have uncompatible types so I even do not know what to suggest.